# Deployed PHP app to Vercel but not working

Tags: php, forms, vercel

I deployed a simple experimental PHP app to Vercel.

This is a data structure

[image]

index.php

[image]

test.php

[image]

vercel.json

[image]

This is a very simple one that has a form containing an input field and submit button in index.php and when I submit, test.php will recieve input data and show it on browser. This is what I am expecting.

It works fine as above in development phase, but when I deploy it to Vercel, it doesn't work.

What happens is a path `/test.php` is just added to the end of URL and the page doesn't change.
How can I make it work?

Comment: As per [ask] please do not post images of code. Code is text. Text from images can't be searched, copied, re-used in answers etc. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the issue in an appropriate format, so it's accessible for people to help you. Thanks

Comment: Could you try 1) replacing the action value from `test.php` to `/test.php` and 2) rearranging the routes so the `test.php` one comes before the regex that gets all pages?